# Place display-only text in textbox for Sudoku

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I am trying to make a Killer Sudoku grid. This involves having jigsaw bold lines inside of regular 3x3 squares. I need to display a number and an operation at the top right of each cell. I have made a table with each cell as a textbox. I need to place some text in the top left corner which cannot disappear or be deleted. the font of this text should be small. I have tried inserting disabled buttons and background images but they all mess up the format of the table.
I know basic javascript html and css.

[This is the image of my table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND0cU.png)

```js
var an=[1,6,2,3,5,4,2,4,3,1,6,5,5,1,4,6,3,2,4,2,6,5,1,3,3,5,1,4,2,6,6,3,5,2,4,1];
var i,k,e;
function show(b,a){
 document.getElementById(b).style.display='block';
 document.getElementById(a).style.display='none';
 return false;
}
function sh(a,b,c,d,e){
 document.getElementById(a).style.display='block';
 document.getElementById(b).style.display='none';
 document.getElementById(c).style.display='none';
 document.getElementById(d).style.display='none';
 document.getElementById(e).style.display='none';
 return false;
}
function hide(b){
  document.getElementById(b).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
function check1(){
 k=0;
 var c=[];
 for(i=1;i<37;i++){
  a=document.getElementById("c1"+i).value;
  c.push(a);
  if(c[i-1]!=an[i-1])
   k++;
 }
 ale(k);
}
function ale(k){
 if(k==0)
  alert("Right");
 else
  alert(k+" digits wrong");
}
```

```css
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #78909c;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#submit{
 margin-left: -63px;
 height:30px;
 width:60px;
 font-size:10px;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
table{
 border: 2px solid #000000;
}
td{
 border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;  
}
input{
    color: transparent;
    border:1px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 black;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
}
input:focus {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.id{
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
}
#c11,#c12,#c13,#c14,#c15,#c16{border-top:3px solid #000000;border-bottom:3px solid #000000;}
#c18,#c19,#c110,#c111,#c131,#c132,#c133,#c134,#c135,#c136{border-bottom:3px solid #000000;}
#c119,#c120,#c121,#c122,#c123,#c124,#c131,#c132,#c133,#c134,#c126,#c127,#c129,#c130{border-top:3px solid #000000;}
#c11,#c17,#c113,#c119,#c125,#c131,#c114,#c120,#c126,#c13,#c133,#c110,#c116,#c122,#c128{border-left:3px solid #000000;}
#c14,#c122,#c134,#c111,#c117,#c129,#c135,#c16,#c112,#c118,#c124,#c130,#c136{border-right:3px solid #000000;}
```

```html
<head>
<div id="p1">
<a href="#" class="button" onclick="return sh('0','p1','p3','p2','p4');">HOME</a><br>
<table style:"align: center;">
<center><strong>KILLER MYSTERY OPERATION<br><br><br></strong></center>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c11">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c12">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c13">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c14">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c15">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c16">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c17">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c18">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c19">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c110">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c111">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c112">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c113">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c114">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c115">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c116">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c117">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c118">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c119">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c120">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c121">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c122">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c123">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c124">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c125">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c126">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c127">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c128">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c129">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c130">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c131">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c132">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c133">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c134">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c135">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="c136">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="r1-1">
<a href="#" class="button" onclick="return show('r1-2','r1-1');">Show rules</a><br>
</div>
<div id="r1-2" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" class="button" onclick="return show('r1-1','r1-2');">Hide rules</a><br>
<ul style="list-style-type:disc">
<li>Fill the grid with number between 1 to 6. No numbers should be repeated in any row or column.</li>
<li>The number in each grid is the target number and the symbol is the operation to be used.</li>
<li>Obtain an expression for a#b in terms of a and b. "x" means multiplication.<br><ul style="list-style-type:disc">
 <li>3 # 1 = (2) x (1)</li>
 <li>4 # 2 = (2) x (2)</li>
 <li>5 # 4 = (1) x (4)</li>
 <li>6 # 1 = (5) x (1)</li>
</ul></li>
<li>"∆" is the inverse operation of "#".<br>Hint:<br>If a # b = c then c ∆ b = a.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<button class="button" id="5" onclick=check1()>Check</button>
</div>
</head>
```

[This is my target.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGBcj.png)

Comment: Have you tried `<fieldset> <legend>Text </legend> .... </fieldset>`

Comment: And this is my result.just joking.please come up with some code you have done

Comment: Did my answer work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the td relative, and keep an absolutely positioned span in it that has the small numbers;
Basically, add these 2 styles and keep an span(that has the small number) just before every input tag in td.

```
td {
  position: relative;
}

td span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```js
var an = [1, 6, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 5, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 2, 6, 5, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1];
var i, k, e;

function show(b, a) {
  document.getElementById(b).style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById(a).style.display = 'none';
  return false;
}

function sh(a, b, c, d, e) {
  document.getElementById(a).style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById(b).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById(c).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById(d).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'none';
  return false;
}

function hide(b) {
  document.getElementById(b).style.display = 'none';
  return false;
}

function check1() {
  k = 0;
  var c = [];
  for (i = 1; i < 37; i++) {
    a = document.getElementById("c1" + i).value;
    c.push(a);
    if (c[i - 1] != an[i - 1])
      k++;
  }
  ale(k);
}

function ale(k) {
  if (k == 0)
    alert("Right");
  else
    alert(k + " digits wrong");
}
```

```css
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><style>.button {
  background-color: #78909c;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#submit {
  margin-left: -63px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 black;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.id {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

#c11,
#c12,
#c13,
#c14,
#c15,
#c16 {
  border-top: 3px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
}

#c18,
#c19,
#c110,
#c111,
#c131,
#c132,
#c133,
#c134,
#c135,
#c136 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
}

#c119,
#c120,
#c121,
#c122,
#c123,
#c124,
#c131,
#c132,
#c133,
#c134,
#c126,
#c127,
#c129,
#c130 {
  border-top: 3px solid #000000;
}

#c11,
#c17,
#c113,
#c119,
#c125,
#c131,
#c114,
#c120,
#c126,
#c13,
#c133,
#c110,
#c116,
#c122,
#c128 {
  border-left: 3px solid #000000;
}

#c14,
#c122,
#c134,
#c111,
#c117,
#c129,
#c135,
#c16,
#c112,
#c118,
#c124,
#c130,
#c136 {
  border-right: 3px solid #000000;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

td span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <div id="p1">
    <a href="#" class="button" onclick="return sh('0','p1','p3','p2','p4');">HOME</a><br>
    <table style: "align: center;">
      <center><strong>KILLER MYSTERY OPERATION<br><br><br></strong></center>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>31</span>
          <input type="text" id="c11">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span></span>
          <input type="text" id="c12">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>27</span>
          <input type="text" id="c13">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span></span>
          <input type="text" id="c14">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span></span>
          <input type="text" id="c15">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>13</span>
          <input type="text" id="c16">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>3</span>
          <input type="text" id="c17">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>16</span>
          <input type="text" id="c18">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c19">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c110">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c111">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c112">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c113">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c114">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c115">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c116">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c117">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c118">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c119">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c120">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c121">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c122">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c123">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c124">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c125">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c126">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c127">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c128">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c129">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c130">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c131">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c132">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c133">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c134">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c135">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="c136">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="r1-1">
      <a href="#" class="button" onclick="return show('r1-2','r1-1');">Show rules</a><br>
    </div>
    <div id="r1-2" style="display:none;">
      <a href="#" class="button" onclick="return show('r1-1','r1-2');">Hide rules</a><br>
      <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
        <li>Fill the grid with number between 1 to 6. No numbers should be repeated in any row or column.</li>
        <li>The number in each grid is the target number and the symbol is the operation to be used.</li>
        <li>Obtain an expression for a#b in terms of a and b. "x" means multiplication.<br>
          <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
            <li>3 # 1 = (2) x (1)</li>
            <li>4 # 2 = (2) x (2)</li>
            <li>5 # 4 = (1) x (4)</li>
            <li>6 # 1 = (5) x (1)</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>"∆" is the inverse operation of "#".<br>Hint:<br>If a # b = c then c ∆ b = a.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="button" id="5" onclick=check1()>Check</button>
  </div>
</head>
```